# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow MySql DB connection open

Tags: c#, mysql, math, overflow, connector

I am using MySql connector 6.6.4 and when i make call to Open method of MySqlConnection ot throws exception :

Arithmetic OverFlow Exception:

i am getting this exception, unable to understand why its happening, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please post your query instead of the screen shot.

Comment: Lots of [possible answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+connection+OverFlowException) out there

Comment: D Stanley please give me solution if you know any?

Comment: Update to MySql Connector 6.6.5 and look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15989284/1050818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I've seen in your screenshot, the exception was thrown during authentication. There's a thread [MySQL Bugs#66647](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66647#c388362) saying it's connector problem.

Check if you're using the right connector on your MySQL.

Comment: i am using mysql connector 6.6.4

Comment: I know, `MySql connector 6.6.4` you've stated that on your first question. What I'm saying here, check your MySQL connector. You can do that by opening the Visual Studio Command then type `gacutil -l mysql.data`.

Comment: Freddie where is visual studio command i have never used and saw it

Comment: See this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/mgoldin/WindowsLiveWriter/VS2010Silverlight4profiling_BD30/image_thumb_1.png

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that your MySQL driver and IIS (which are running) use the same compiler platform  (either x86 or x64) both must be matched.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to save the values whose size is less than given value,
please make sure that you are passing the correct in put to Query.